# AngularJS calculated ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have following controller.

```
app.controller("testCtrl", function(){

    $scope.utcTime = 1380150771;
    $scope.parseTime = function(t){
      //return local time string
    }
});
```

In the view, I have

```
<input type="text" ng-model="parseTime(utcTime)" />
```

Its not working. Can I bind ng-model to a method that returns the string ?
Any alternative way to show the value in the input button ?

Comment: I don't believe you can have ng-model bound to a function, are you just trying to set the initial value to that hardcoded utcTime?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to show the value. I am not binding anything. Also I need to detect change in value as well when the user sets the date

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngChange and ngModel both

JS

```
$scope.utcTime = 1380150771;
$scope.parseTime = function(){
  console.log($scope.utcTime);
  //return local time string
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-change="parseTime()" ng-model="utcTime" />
```

ng-model is mapping through tag and controller.

At first you can see default utcTime (1380150771) that you assign in input tag.

And when you change the text in input tag, ng-model(utcTime) will be changed automatically in the controller.

Then each letter that you typed will call ng-change(parseTime) function.

You can check by console.log method.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on this source:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/1mnra0vamtg

I have edited the Plunker sample code to use `ng-value` to generate and update `ng-model` using calculation function. See this link below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fmqw0wp37Ndk1yuWvFkV?p=preview

Also, the above sample shows you how you format the result for display using custom filter.

In other posts, some have suggested using `$watch()` to detect change to input variables and update `ng-model` variable accordingly. Using `ng-value` is much better than using `$watch()` since the latter forces you to include all input variables in the watch which may be impossible if you have very complex calculation model.

Tarek

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
 app.controller("testCtrl", function(){

        $scope.utcTime = 1380150771;
$scope.result= $scope.parseTime( $scope.utcTime)
        $scope.parseTime = function(t){
          //return local time string
        }
    });
```

html

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="result" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try follwing:
its working example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="parseTime(utcTime)" />

app.controller("testCtrl", function(){

    $scope.utcTime = 1380150771;
    $scope.parseTime = function(t){
      //return local time string
      new Date(t).toISOString();
    }
});
```